# vb.net linq where clause for mutiple search filter - same query but different where clause

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I know this question was answered in c# but when I try to covert it online from c# to vb.net I got running errors.

*disclaimer this is **not** my code*

```
   string personName = txtPersonName.Text;
   int personAge = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text);
   var opportunites =  from p in this.DataContext.Persons
                        select new
                        {
                            p.PersonID,
                            p.Name,
                            p.Age,
                            p.Gender
                        };

    if (personsID != 0)
        opportunites = opportunites.Where(p => p.PersonID == personID);

    if (personName != string.Empty)
        opportunites = opportunites.Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(personName));

    if (personAge != 0)
        opportunites = opportunites.Where(p => p.Age == personAge);
```

can someone help me to convert this code I think it is c#, but can I can't convert it properly to vb.net i tried [telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/)
but no luck.

I can't call/use the 'p' in linq select new {} on my if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two areas you seem to be having problems with: the anonymous type and the lambdas - the conversion below should clarify these issues:
Option Infer On

```
Dim personName As String = txtPersonName.Text
Dim personAge As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text)
Dim opportunites = From p In Me.DataContext.Persons
    Select New With {
        Key p.PersonID,
        Key p.Name,
        Key p.Age,
        Key p.Gender
    }

If personsID <> 0 Then
    opportunites = opportunites.Where(Function(p) p.PersonID = personID)
End If

If personName <> String.Empty Then
    opportunites = opportunites.Where(Function(p) p.Name.StartsWith(personName))
End If

If personAge <> 0 Then
    opportunites = opportunites.Where(Function(p) p.Age = personAge)
End If
```

Comment: Dude you are awesome! thanks. maybe later i'll research why it works!

Answer (score 0):

just select the values you want. the anonymous type is implied in vb

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384767.aspx

```
Dim personName As String = "Joe"
Dim personAge As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(5)
Dim opportunites = From p IN AspNetUsers
                   Select p.Id,
                          p.FirstName,
                          p.LastName

If (personAge <> 0)
    opportunites = From o In opportunites Where o.Id >= 10
End If
```

Comment: how about the if statement block how do I call the 'p.PersonID' just like in the example?

Comment: i changed the first if from personId to personAge since you didn't declare personId in your example. i was getting a compiler error